# Force HTTPS using .htaccess doesn't always work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting, redirect

with this rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For API
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule (^api\/) api.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect 301: from http to https    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

the redirect works correctly in this case:

- http://www.example.com/something_else ->
  https://www.example.com/something_else
- http://example.com/something_else ->
  https://example.com/something_else

but not in these case

- http://www.example.com
- http://example.com

Response header

[image]
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test in chrome dev tool with caching disabled and paste response headers in question.

Comment: @anubhava I added the response header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way with a different order of rules and `DirectoryIndex` directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect 301: from http to https and www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^ - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# For API
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/ api.php [NC,L]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing to avoid old cache.